# Adding my SSH key to new user with only SSH access through key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys, user-management

I'm quite new to this, and I've looked through questions but haven't found one that quite matches my problem, or rather I didn't sufficiently understand them to be able to solve this issue.

I have a new server to which I can only access using a pre-generated SSH RSA key pair, which allows me to connect only to the default `ubuntu` user

`ssh -i .ssh/mykey ubuntu@ipaddr`

On the server I created a new user, `newuser`, and I'm trying to make it, so I can use my key that I connect to `ubuntu` on that account as well, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this, so I can then delete the `ubuntu` user.

`ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/mykey.pub -o "IdentityFile .ssh/mykey" newuser@ipaddr`

That though returns permission denied. How can I do this effectively? Any password login is disabled and can't be enabled in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ssh to your old user `ubuntu`
- use `sudo -i -u newuser` to switch to the new user
- open `~newuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` with your favourite editor and  copy&paste the content of your new public key into it
- set proper permissions on the `.ssh` directory and the files inside it.

you may need to create the directory `~newuser/.ssh` if it doesn't exist yet

Comment: Don't forget to give sudo access to your new user before you delete the old one.